# Can we take advantage of nanopore sequencing systematic errors to predict secondary structure motifs?

Tags: dna-sequencing, rna-sequencing

One of the methods of single-molecule sequencing, Nanopore sequencing, is based on traversal of DNA strand through a nanopore. Nucleotide is determined by measurement of ion current (when nucleotide passes through the pore, it decreases the current of ions through the pore, which can be measured).

The method is known for producing systematic errors. I.e. if you sequenced the same molecule twice and during the first run Adenine in 255th position was confused with Guanine, it will be confused again if you repeat the experiment.

I wonder, if it's possible to make use of information about location of errors to predict secondary structure of DNA/RNA etc.? It is natural to suppose that presence or absence of errors is determined by the context, where a nucleotide is located. If I want to validate the hypothesis that same errors are produced by the same motifs of secondary structure, where can I get the raw data to validate this theory?

[image]